# EnableOAuth2Client deprecated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

Currently, I am using Spring Boot 2.2.5 Release. Documentation looks incomplete. What is the replacement for `@EnableOAuth2Client` or `@EnableOAuth2Sso`.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btIWt.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do it via the **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter's** configure method, instead of annotations.

1. EnableOAuth2Sso is now this:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login(); // sso           
   }
   ```
2. @EnableOAuth2Client is now this (for full examples and config options, see  [Spring's migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide)):

   ```
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
           .oauth2Client();
   }
   ```

Comment: Since it mentions "Web" in its class name would it be able to security API only resources? no UI.